# How to change property of vue app from outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wonder how to change the property of a vue app from outside. So I want to create a new vue app called app and set app.propertyName = someValue, but as tried below, that doesn't work. How could you achieve it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The template configuration option</title>
  <style>
    #app {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: x-large;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>'template' Example</h1>

  <p>All HTML code from inside the div tag with id="app" is moved inside the 'template' configuration option, in backtick quotes.</p>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

  <script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      template: `<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <p>This is a second line of HTML code, inside backtick quotes</p>`,
      data() {
        return {
          message: "Hello World!"
        }
      }
    })

    app.mount('#app');
    app.message = "My name is Florian"; //This line of code doesn't work
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $data to access or edit the message like :

```js
 app.$data.message = "My name is Florian"; // Access the reactive data object using $data
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3, you can access the app's instance through the `_instance` property and fiddle around with it:

```
app._instance.data.message = "Your name is Florian";
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: `<h1>{{ message }}</h1>`,
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello World!"
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
app._instance.data.message = "Your name is Florian";
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that application instance is accessed, while it's root component instance that needs to be in this case.

It should be:

```
const vm = app.mount('#app');
vm.message = "My name is Florian";
```

It's a bad practice to modify private data from the outside as this breaks the encapsulation. If this is the intended behaviour, component [public API](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#expose) should preferably be defined:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  ...
  expose: ['setMessage'],
  methods: {
    setMessage(message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
  }
});

const vm = app.mount('#app');
vm.setMessage("My name is Florian");
```